# Color out a row in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid whose values get populated based on a post call. I need to gray out an entire row if one of the column has a value "REGISTERED".

Is there a way we can achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name", title: "Release Name" },
    { field: "number", title: "Number" },
    { field: "status", title: "Registration Status" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", number: "50", status: "REGISTERED" },
    { name: "John Doe", number: "60", status: "NOT REGISTERED" }
  ]
});
```

Comment: See http://daveaglick.com/posts/simple-row-coloring-in-kendo-grid

Comment: Perfect. It worked fine. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the style of a kendo grid element, you should do it on the [dataBound event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound).  When this event will be fired, all the view element will be rendered and you'll be able to retrieve a specific DOM element based on the dataItem's uid.

```
$("#YourGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataBound: function() {
        $.each($("#YourGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.view(), function (index, viewDataItem) {
            var row = $("#YourGrid").find("tbody>tr[data-uid='" + viewDataItem.uid + "']");
            if (viewDataItem.status == "REGISTERED") {
                row.css("background-color", "red"); //Use row.find("td") if you want to set the style at the cell level
            } else {
                row.css("background-color", "");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just check this fiddle link

I have created demo grid example using kendo's dataSource

[Fiddle Link For Kendo Grid Row Background Color](http://jsfiddle.net/7ukt9ran/)

```
Hope This May Help You.
```